# load on startup tag in web.xml

Tags: java, tomcat, jboss

am working on EJB 1.0 Application. I want to start my schedular servlet on jboss server startup for that i put.
         `<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>` in my `web.xml`. After adding this tag to my application taking nearly 45 min to start. I don't know problem in that.

Here is my `web.xml` file

Thanks in Advance.

```
<web-app id="WebApp"> 
    <display-name></display-name>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Main</servlet-name>
        <display-name>Main</display-name>
        <servlet-class>control.Main</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>TimerLoader</servlet-name>
        <display-name>TimerLoader</display-name>
        <servlet-class>timer.TimerLoader</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>SchedulerMain</servlet-name>
        <display-name>SchedulerMain</display-name>
        <servlet-class>admin.SchedulerMain</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>FileDownload</servlet-name>
        <display-name>FileDownLoad</display-name>
        <servlet-class>control.FileDownload</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Main</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/Main</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>TimerLoader</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/TimerLoader</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>SchedulerMain</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/SchedulerMain</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>FileDownload</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/FileDownLoad</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>/Main</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <resource-ref>
        <res-ref-name>jdbc/TEST5</res-ref-name>
        <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
        <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
    </resource-ref>
</web-app>
```

Comment: There's nothing wrong in your `web.xml`. Add some logging to our servlet initialization code, and see what takes so long.

Comment: You are using EJB 1.0? are you sure?

Answer (score 1):

If the only setting load-on-startup to 1 make your application to take long time to load, it should mean that you initialization code take that time.

As you speak of a schedule servlet, I would guest that you may have blocking logic in the schedule init logic.

The init call should only setup the servlet and should return as soon as possible to improve app start up time.  You need to manage your self the scheduling threading and not use the init calling thread for other thing than initialization.